# malloc causes int to change value

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory

I'm a bit new to C, and have been working on a project when I came across a weird behavior which I'd love to understand. (Probably something I'm missing).

I have the following structs:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    int status;
    int strength;
} Pig;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char color[10];
    int injuryPower;
    int penType;
} Bird;
```

When I allocate the pig, like this, it works normally:

```
Pig *pig_1 = malloc(sizeof(Pig *));
pig_1->status = 2;
pig_1->strength = 7;
pig_1->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 11);
pig_1->name = "PigA\0";
```

But when I allocate the bird, in a similar manner, I have this weird behavior:

```
Bird *bird_1 = malloc(sizeof(Bird *));
1) bird_1->penType = 2;
2) bird_1->injuryPower = 5;
3) bird_1->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
bird_1->name = "BirdA\0";
bird_1->color[0] = 'R';
bird_1->color[1] = 'e';
bird_1->color[2] = 'd';
bird_1->color[3] = '\0';
```

In line (1) pen type is getting defined to 2.

In line (2) pen type is still 2.
In line (3) pen type gets changed according to the value I define in the bracets, so in this example it'll change to 35.

I am using Cygwin 64 bit as my compiler.

Could someone please explain what I am missing here, why is the value of pen type changing even though I am not altering it?

Is it due to malloc? Am I doing something incorrectly?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: *malloc causes int to change value* - nope. Won't happen.

Comment: `Pig *pig_1 = malloc(sizeof(Pig *));` is the size of a POINTER to Pig.  sizeof(Pig) is the isze of a Pig

Comment: *In line (3) pen type gets changed according to the value I define in the bracets, so in this example it'll change to 35.* – How do you determine that? and where should the 35 come from? [Tom Lehrer - Poisoning Pigeons in the Park](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNA9rQcMq00&t=20)

Comment: @Swordfish Obviously malloc isn't causing this, I'm just too new to understand what is causing this.
I determine this because further in the code there is usage of the value of pentype, and due to the change in value it "messes up" the rest of the program.

I use the debug feature in my IDE to examine this and see the value change upon the first malloc I perform.

Comment: Yes, you mess up. After `Pig *pig_1 = malloc(sizeof(Pig *));` you have a pointer to a `Pig` called `pig_1` that points to some memory big enough to hold a pointer to a `Pig`. Not more, not less. Everything else you do is undefined behaviour, because there is no `Pig`, only pointers to `Pig`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, you guys are right!

Comment: That's practically Zen. _There is no pig._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pig *pig_1 = malloc(sizeof(Pig *));
...
Bird *bird_1 = malloc(sizeof(Bird *));
```

You're allocating the size of a pointer not the size of the structure.

```
Pig *pig_1 = malloc(sizeof(Pig));
...
Bird *bird_1 = malloc(sizeof(Bird));
```

Will reserve enough space for the whole structure.

Because you are only allocating enough memory for the first member of your structure (also a pointer), the other members are in an area of memory that could be reserved for other variables.  What you are seeing is the value of another variable being changed and reflected in your structure.

Comment: I just tested that, you are right. Thanks! I'll mark this as the answer in a few minutes (once it lets me).
Still kinda new, just recently got the hang of stack and heap, trying to incorporate structures now as well. Thanks again!